# Stylizing a table in HTML

Tags: html, html-table

So I have a table.

First thing I want to do is put some space between two rows of the table. I tried inserting a `<br />` in between the two `<tr>` elements, but that only put space above the ENTIRE table (don't know why).

Second thing I want to do is center a picture in a column so it lines up in the middle of the text in the column below it. I tried placing an `align=center` on the `<td>` element to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried changing the CSS for the table rows and possibly adding a : `padding-bottom: x px;` or `margin-bottom: x px;` to gain the space that you would like in the table.

Also - I believe that you would need your `"align=center"` property to be a `"text-align: center"`.

Comment: To be a little more explicit, your ` "align=center" ` should actually be a ` style="text-align:center;" ` when used in the html tag. You can simply use ` text-align: center; ` inside of a css style block.

Answer (score 1):

Putting spaces between the table rows won't work. All that content will be placed above or below the table. Styling the table must be done using CSS. Try something like:

```
td{
   padding: 5px 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS, as HTML is for structure.  Here is a link to W3C tutorial on [styling tables with css](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_table.asp)  In fact, if you are using tables for positioning, that is bad practice too - again use CSS.